# Show DialogFragment with animation growing from a point

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I'm showing a `DialogFragment` when the user taps on a row in a `ListView`. I'd like to animate the showing of the dialog so that it grows from the center of the row. A similar effect can be seen when opening a folder from the launcher.

One idea that I've had is a combination of `TranslateAnimation` and `ScaleAnimation`. Is there another way?

Comment: Refer to the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/0oCWqQC4Pww) for animations on DialogFragment.

Answer (score 196):

Being `DialogFragment` a wrapper for the `Dialog` class, you should set a theme to your base `Dialog` to get the animation you want:

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnEditorActionListener
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Set a theme on the dialog builder constructor!
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder( getActivity(), R.style.MyCustomTheme );
    
        builder  
        .setTitle( "Your title" )
        .setMessage( "Your message" )
        .setPositiveButton( "OK" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {      
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              dismiss();                  
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Then you just need to define the theme that will include your desired animation. In **styles.xml** add your custom theme:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity"> 
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_out</item>
</style>
```

Now add the animation files in the **res/anim** folder:

( the `android:pivotY` is the key )

**anim_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200" 
        android:pivotX = "50%"
        android:pivotY = "-90%"
    />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="50%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200"
    />
</set>
```

**anim_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="200" 
        android:pivotX = "50%"        
        android:pivotY = "-90%"        
    />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="50%"
        android:duration="200"
    />
</set>
```

Finally, the tricky thing here is to get your animation grow from the center of each row. I suppose the row is filling the screen horizontally so, on one hand the `android:pivotX` value will be static. On the other hand, you can't modify the `android:pivotY` value programmatically.

What I suggest is, you define several animations each of which having a different percentage value on the `android:pivotY` attribute (and several themes referencing those animations). Then, when the user taps the row, calculate the Y position in percentage of the row on the screen. Knowing the position in percentage, assign a theme to your dialog that has the appropriate `android:pivotY` value.

It is not a perfect solution but could do the trick for you. If you don't like the result, then I would suggest forgetting the `DialogFragment` and animating a simple `View` growing from the exact center of the row.

Comment: Good idea with the multiple animations for different locations on the screen. It's a hack, but it seems to be the only way.

Comment: This will only wok with > API 11 @Kiran Babu answer is a work around

Comment: Do you know if there's a possible way to get a callback when these animations are completed? I'd like to do a 2-part animation, one where the dialog slides in, and then fading the views in. 

How would I attaach a listener to the windowAnimations?

Comment: Exelent! It is exectly that i have looked for!

Comment: Setting theme can be as simple as doing `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyCustomTheme)` on `onCreate(bundle)`
See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: not work for me, need remove parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity" and style for dialog.

Comment: Is there a solution with transition API for 21+?

Comment: your animations are awesome, Is it possible to find more of these xml files (some kind of a library of animations)

Answer (score 140):

Check it out this code, it works for me

// Slide up animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

// Slide dowm animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

// Style

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
</style>
```

// Inside Dialog Fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
    getDialog().getWindow()
    .getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: This might not be exactly what the OP is asking for, but it's a good entry point, I think.

Comment: Excellent example! The only sample that worked for me. Trick is to set animation/theme in onActivityCreated(...) method

Comment: This may be useful but it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Do you know if there's a possible way to get a callback when these animations are completed? I'd like to do a 2-part animation, one where the dialog slides in, and then fading the views in. 

How would I attaach a listener to the windowAnimations?

Comment: I have tried this and it works, but when I change the animation duration I have to do an actual uninstall and reinstall of my app to see my changes take effect. Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: @tomurka Why does it not work in `onStart()`? Why it has to be placed in `onActivityCreated()`?

Comment: Minor adjustment:
android:toXDelta="0"
should be
android:toYDelta="0"
in slide up anim.

Comment: any one have kotlin equivalent code (for calling)

Comment: For anyone wondering in Kotlin you have to set the animation res like this
`dialog.window.setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogPop)` since `dialog.window.attributes.windowAnimations` is immutable

Answer (score 31):

DialogFragment has a public getTheme() method that you can over ride for this exact reason. This solution uses less lines of code:

```
public class MyCustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
    ...
    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.MyThemeWithCustomAnimation;
    }
}
```

Comment: While not related to the original question, I had a gallery shown in MainAcitvity where user click will activate the slideshow in DialogFragment. There is however a jerk in the MainActivity whenever returning from the slideshow. This is due to MainActivity using `AppTheme.NoActionBar` while the DialogFragment is using the default `AppTheme`. The method above solved my problem by having consistent theme in both fragment and activity.

Comment: This solution worked for me. However one thing confused me; setting windowEnterAnimation or windowExitAnimation directly in the Theme would make not difference in my DialogFragments animations. The only thing that worked for me was setting windowAnimationStyle to a separate XML file that defined the style and setting the enter and exit animations there

Comment: Would you please show the xml code of MyThemeWithCustomAnimation?

Answer (score 14):

To get a full-screen dialog with animation, write the following ...

**Styles:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreenDialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.WindowSlideUpDown</item>
</style>

<style name="Animation.WindowSlideUpDown" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
</style>
```

**res/anim/slide_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quad">

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"/>
</set>
```

**res/anim/slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quad">

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%"/>
</set>
```

**Java code:**

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_FullScreenDialog;
    }
}

private void showDialog() {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment previous = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyDialog.class.getName());
    if (previous != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(previous);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
    dialog.show(fragmentTransaction, MyDialog.class.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In DialogFragment, custom animation is called onCreateDialog. 'DialogAnimation' is custom animation style in previous answer.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to work over APIs you have to do inside your DialogFragemnt->onStart and not inside onCreateDialog

```
@Override
    public void onStart() 
    {
        if (getDialog() == null) 
        {
            return;
        }

        getDialog().getWindow().setWindowAnimations(
                  R.style.DlgAnimation);

        super.onStart();
    }
```

Comment: Best solution in my opinion. It works for AlertDialogs as well, just use it in the onShowListener. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use decor view inside onStart in your dialog fragment

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    final View decorView = getDialog()
            .getWindow()
            .getDecorView();

    decorView.animate().translationY(-100)
            .setStartDelay(300)
            .setDuration(300)
            .start();

}
```

Comment: The underlying view does not seem to be clickable afterwards

Answer (score 3):

Note: This is just a complement to other answers.

No matter which the solutions you pick you might have the same problem as me.

I need to UNINSTALL the game from my development device before installing the new version for the animation changes to take effect.

I am not sure why but I guess it has to do with the optimized deployment on Android studio not recognizing the changes.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THIS. I was going insane because it wasn't working. Needed to uninstall the app and reinstall for it to work.

Comment: Another reason why I hate updating Android Studio. Always a version that's broken. Before update I've never had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Android Developers Training on [Zooming a View](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)? Might be a good starting point.

You probably want to create a custom class extending `DialogFragment` to get this working.

Also, take a look at Jake Whartons [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) for Honeycomb Animation API compatibility all the way back to API Level 1.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code on values anim

```
 <scale
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXScale="0.2"
    android:fromYScale="0.2"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.1"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
```

call on styles.xml

```
<style name="DialogScale">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/scale_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/scale_out</item>
</style>
```

On java code: set Onclick

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        fab_onclick(R.style.DialogScale, "Scale" ,(Activity) context,getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView());
      //  Dialogs.fab_onclick(R.style.DialogScale, "Scale");

    }
```

setup on method:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = type;
```