# How to add animation to DialogFragment?

Tags: android, animation

How can I add animation to DialogFragment. My animations are:

out anim:

```
<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="-90%"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" />

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-200"
    android:toYDelta="-200" />
```

in anim:

```
<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="-90%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="-200"
    android:fromYDelta="-200"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

and my code:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.jump_in, R.anim.jump_out, R.anim.jump_in, R.anim.jump_out);
                ft.add(layer_frag, "layer frag");
                ft.show(layer_frag).commit();//layer_frag is a class whitch extends DialogFragment
```

I must miss something because it appears as it appears before.

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13537234/969325. In short you have to hack your way around it as there is no build in way.

Comment: Probably not, because I did that to and it does not work for me as well :( it changed the layout a bit but the animation does not apear

Comment: Then I think you are left with making your own Fragment which appears as a dialog.

Comment: // Pick a style based on the num.
  int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE;
  setStyle(style, R.style.MyCustomTheme);

Comment: Like this I have set the style and the custom theme, but the animation is left out :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.detailDialogAnimation;
    return dialog;
}
```

The answer was from [stackoverflow.com/a/13537234/969325](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13537234/969325) but You have to set the style at `onCreateDialog` function.

Comment: Do you know if there's a possible way to get a callback when these animations are completed? I'd like to do a 2-part animation, one where the dialog slides in, and then fading the views in. 

How would I attaach a listener to the windowAnimations?

Comment: setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    
    
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
    }
    
    
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
    }
    
   
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
     ladder.startAnimation(toRight);
     
    }
   });

Comment: You don't have to set the style in `onCreateDialog`, as you can get the dialog using `getDialog` at any time after `onCreateDialog` has been called. I'm calling it in `onViewCreated` for example.