# Animate custom Dialog programmatically

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialog

I would like to set some animations to my custom dialog and I would like to do it programmatically. I know I can do it like this with xml animations:

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_down</item>
</style>


Dialog imageDiaglog= new Dialog(MainActivity.this,R.style.DialogAnimation);
```

But I would like to do it programmatically. How can I set my programmatically created animations to Dialog's show() and hide() methods?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cant because the dialog uses the style element for the animation transition.
And You cannot set the style elements programmatically.

Comment: OK thanks..It`s possible with FragmentDialog programatically?

Comment: If possible please post your answer.I give bounty to you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DialogFragment` and set the animation in `onCreateDialog(Dialog)` or `onStart()`. Example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15088427/1048340):

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.detailDialogAnimation;
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: I need animation programatically.. not from animation file

Comment: You should be able to use `getDialog().getWindow().setEnterTransition(yourTransition);`. You may need to call `dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);`