# Open dialog from view position

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to animate a dialog open from view position. I want that my dialog shows from a button position for example and hides to the same position when dismissed.

this thread [Animate a custom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817014/animate-a-custom-dialog) gave me an idea and i came to this xml:

```
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="20%p"
    android:pivotY="20%p"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

but i dont know how to dynamically set an start position, cause my button change position.

any idea?

tks a lot....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show DialogFragment with animation growing from a point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402782/show-dialogfragment-with-animation-growing-from-a-point)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method [*getLocationOnScreen()*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) from the View class to get the current position from the button or any other view you want to use as an anchor.

**Edit** -
Or you may find useful to use instead of Dialog a [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) using the coordinates that you can get through getLocationOnScreen in method [showAtLocation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: that wasn't the question. The dialog should be always in center. What I want is to set an open scale animation to this dialog an set the start position to this scale. For example: the dialog will star on position x=20,y=200 and get bigger, and bigger till it`s size on center screen. Got it?

Comment: Ok, I got, so forget the showAtLocation and use getLocationOnScreen to get the Button position, but you will need to calculate the animation on the fly to get it right. I don't know any ready animation to solve this, sorry.

Comment: That's my problem. Animate on the fly :D . I know it is possible because facebook do that. But still didnt find the way. =/