# Scale up Dialog transition with AppCompat

Tags: android, transition

Do you know, how to implement a scale up transition for a simple dialogue in L (Android 5.0) with ActivityOptionsCompat?

I have an activity with a button (mButton). When the button is pushed (onClick), then a dialogue (mDialog) will be created and started (mDialog.show).

I try to figure out, how can I use ActivityOptionsCompat to create a transitions which looks like as the dialogue would come from the position of the button.

Comment: Maybe use a DialogFragment instead of a Dialog and try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402782/show-dialogfragment-with-animation-growing-from-a-point