# How to add shaking animation to a DialogFragment

Tags: android, animation

I have a DialogFragment that asking user to input a password. When user enter at most 4 digits, I want to shake the DialogFragment (just like MacOS login dialog does).

I try to shake it by starting an animation on DialogFragment.getView() but no effect.

How to implement it?

EDIT:
Note that I am not looking for any animation XML file that shows/hides a fragment. What I want is **HOW** to play an animation on a **DialogFragment** that is already on the screen, and after animation playing done, the DialogFragment should still exist on screen.

Comment: Use this to code the animation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402782/show-dialogfragment-with-animation-growing-from-a-point

Comment: And use this xml code https://gist.github.com/simon-heinen/9795036 for applying the shake animation

Answer (score 2):

A view which can be animated needs a parent view in it's attached window. However, Dialog itself has a window,so only its content part can be animated, You can implement `onCreateView` in `DialogFragment`to give the dialog a custom layout content, then the custom part can be animated.