# Adding animation to the closing of DialogFragment when tapping outside

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am new to Android development (from Swift/iOS).  I am trying to add some animation to this closing of a `DialogFragment` when I tap outside the view. I have read various posts on animation for Dialogs and found posts that helped to get this far for my solution.

What works:

- Nicely scales up  and fades in the alert (the `onStart()` is working)
- Nicely scales down and fades out the alert when the "Close" button is
  tapped (the `onClick()` is working)

What does not work:

- Tapping outside the alert.  It closes the alert without the graceful animation.

Technically this is for:

1. `DialogFragment`
2. Using an `AlertDialog.Builder`
3. The `cancelable` property is set to true on the builder
4. The `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` property is set to true on the created `AlertDialog`.
5. Using `ObjectAnimator` for my animations
6. For customer compliance, I need to support both a close button and "tap outside" to cancel/dismiss the dialog.
7. From my discovery `onCancel` happens before `onDismiss`

Issues:

I was excited to add an `OnCancelListener` to my dialog.  However, during runtime I received an error, basically stating

> Note: DialogFragment own the Dialog.setOnCancelListener and Dialog.setOnDismissListener callbacks. You must not set them yourself. To find out about these events, override onCancel(DialogInterface) and onDismiss(DialogInterface).

Ok.  Easy enough, I thought I would override `OnCancel`.

I did, but the animation does occur when I tap outside the alert dialog fragment.  It still cancels (closes) - just no animation.  Debugging, I see it step into my code, but the alert is already closed/hide/canceled as soon as I enter the overridden `onCancel()` method.  It seems like I am too late in the lifecycle.  Since I cannot override `OnCancelListener` for `DialogFragments`, I was wondering if anyone has a solution or insight into my dilemma.

Long and Short:
I would like to be able to have the same animation I have for clicking on the dialog's close button as I do when clicking outside the alert.

Here is my code snippet:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog)getDialog();
    ObjectAnimator scaleUp = scaleUp(dialog);
    scaleUp.start();

    Button closeButton = dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog)getDialog();
            ObjectAnimator scaleDown = scaleDown(dialog);
            scaleDown.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    dismiss();
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                }
            });
            scaleDown.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the onCancel override:

```
    @Override
public void onCancel(final DialogInterface dialog) {

    ObjectAnimator scaleDown = scaleDown((AlertDialog)dialog);
    scaleDown.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Log.i("DialogFragment","onAnimationEnd");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            Log.i("DialogFragment","onAnimationStart");
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
                          });
    scaleDown.start();


}
```

The two methods `scaleUp` and `scaleDown` are just refactored, they are just the settings for the `ObjectAnimator`.

**Followup**: 
The inspiration of my solution was found in the one marked as possible duplicate. [Change DialogFragment enter/exit transition at just before dismissing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908279/change-dialogfragment-enter-exit-transition-at-just-before-dismissing), however this does not address the specifics situation I had outlined - animation when tapping outside the dialog.

The solution I used from that link is great close animating when tapping on a button inside the dialog, but does not handle the `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change DialogFragment enter/exit transition at just before dismissing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908279/change-dialogfragment-enter-exit-transition-at-just-before-dismissing)

Comment: I added a followup.  This was one of the major links I used to help me form my solution, but it does not address my issue with tapping outside the alert dialog (setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true))