# Slide in dialog fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I have a custom DialogFragment

```
class CompactPickerFragment : DialogFragment()
```

By default it fades in, I want to make it slide in from the bottom.

I have tried the following things (all except one found on stack overflow):

First define a style like:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Some parent, I've tried different parents here"> //
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>
```

The slide animations work in other parts of the app when sliding fragment. Set this theme in various ways:

```
class CompactPickerFragment : DialogFragment() {

    // Attempt 1
    override fun getTheme() = R.style.DialogTheme

   // Attempt 2
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {         
       val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!, R.style.DialogTheme)
        return builder.create()
   }

    // Attempt 3
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.DialogTheme)
```

These attempts roughylu all gave this 'without changes'-'with changes' picture(and no animation happens):

[image: beforeafter]

And I also tried setting a enter transistion, but havn't managed to get that to do anything:

```
private fun ShowPicker() {
    val slide = Slide()
    slide.duration = 1000
    slide.slideEdge = Gravity.BOTTOM
    slide.mode = MODE_IN
    val dialog = CompactPickerFragment.newOperandInstance()
    dialog.enterTransition = slide
    dialog.show(fragmentManager, CompactPickerFragment.TAG)
}
```

How do you supply a transition/animation to a custom dialog fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this [show-dialogfragment-with-animation-growing-from-a-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402782/show-dialogfragment-with-animation-growing-from-a-point?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: The solutions from that one is what what I've tried in my original question, unsure what I've done wrong/missed though

Comment: make sure to pass style before set content view