# Does the Navigation component support animation of Dialog Fragments?

Tags: androidx, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I spent 2hrs trying to animate the enter/exit animation on an DialogFragment i want to show. The Android Doc and also the Mad Skills Tutorials ignore this topic completely i think.

So the general question is, does anyone got an animation working with them which not end in a big hack using window animation and so on ?

If someone can point me in some direction this would be nice.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462884/navigation-architecture-component-transition-animations-not-working-for-dialog.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigation Architecture Component: transition animations not working for dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462884/navigation-architecture-component-transition-animations-not-working-for-dialog)